# Plotting in R won't plot type = "l"

Tags: r

When I run this line:

```
plot(z$prod,z$x, type="l")
```

It plots the values as dashes and ignores the type command.
I can easily get it to plot the line if I run:

```
points(z$prod, z$x, type="l")
```

What is it about `plot()` that ignores the type command while `points()` recognizes it?

- `z$prod` is a factor with 4 levels
- `z$x` is a num[1:6]

This is driving me crazy!

Comment: I have never seen this behavior, what kind of data is it? is.numeric(z$prod) is.factor(z$x)

Comment: Method dispatch. You should read `?plot.factor`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expanding on my comment...

The second paragraph you read when looking up `?plot` (you *did* read `?plot` right?) is this:

> For simple scatter plots, `plot.default` will be used. However, there
>   are `plot` methods for many R objects, including `functions`, `data.frame`s,
>   `density` objects, etc. Use `methods(plot)` and the documentation for
>   these.

Then continue reading about the `type` argument:

> `type`: what type of plot should be drawn [...] Note that some methods, e.g. `plot.factor`, do *not* accept this

---

Typing `methods(plot)` lists a whole bunch of functions. You note that your x values are a factor. Hmmm. There's a `plot.factor` listed in there. I wonder what it does. Turning next to `?plot.factor` we see that:

> ...For numeric `y` a `boxplot` is used...

And further,

> Further arguments to `barplot`, `boxplot`, `spineplot` or `plot` as
>   appropriate. All of these accept graphical parameters (see `par`) and
>   annotation arguments passed to `title` and `axes = FALSE`. None accept
>   `type`.

There. Mystery solved.

Comment: So, just to clarify, you think the OP should read `?plot` ? :-P

Answer (score 0):

In other words, your `z$prod` data can't be a factor.  Changing it to a character will likely get you the result you're looking for:

```
as.character(z$prod)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is

```
plot(z$prod,z$x, type="l")
```

**not**

```
plot(z$prod,z$x, type="1")
```

I mean it is the letter "l", not the number "1".

Comment: Looks to me like the OP has a lower case L in his code, not a digit 1.