# Why don't my base plot type="b" produce a line and symbols?

Tags: r, plot

I have now spent too much time trying to make my very simple script produce a base plot with a line and symbols, but to me it only produces the following plot with horisontal line segments, which it shouldn't. This should be very simple, but something is wrong.

[image]

My script:

```
 plot(sumtab$Year,sumtab$Count,type='b',pch=19,xlab="",ylab="",col='black',cex.lab=1.5,las=1)
```

My dataframe:

```
dput(sumtab)
structure(list(Year = structure(1:43, .Label = c("1938", "1939", 
"1940", "1941", "1942", "1943", "1944", "1945", "1946", "1947", 
"1948", "1949", "1950", "1951", "1952", "1953", "1954", "1955", 
"1956", "1957", "1958", "1959", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", 
"1964", "1965", "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", 
"1972", "1973", "1974", "1975", "1977", "1978", "1979", "1980", 
"1981"), class = "factor"), Count = c(49L, 23L, 7L, 14L, 57L, 
13L, 28L, 12L, 32L, 29L, 43L, 34L, 12L, 24L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 26L, 
40L, 48L, 39L, 69L, 82L, 112L, 124L, 90L, 77L, 104L, 162L, 36L, 
86L, 231L, 246L, 57L, 28L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 64L, 221L, 52L, 13L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -43L))
```

Comment: I think the problem is in your x variable - it is a factor, while it should be a numeric. I am not very familiar with `plot()` function, but I can solve it with `ggplot2` with a factor as x variable if you want

Comment: Related: [Plotting in R won't plot type = "l"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848937/plotting-in-r-wont-plot-type-l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd rather not change the data you can transform your x variable into numeric during plotting

```
plot(as.numeric(as.character(sumtab$Year)),sumtab$Count,type='b')
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to specify the x-variable, R will take its indices:

```
plot(sumtab$Count,
     type='b',
     pch=19,
     xaxt = "n",
     xlab="", ylab="", col='black', cex.lab=1.5, las=1)
axis(1, at = 1:nrow(sumtab), labels = sumtab$Year, las = 2)
```

[image]